# Calling numpy functions

Tags: python, numpy

Is it okay to call any numpy function without using the library name before the function (example: `numpy.linspace()`)? Can we call it simply

> linspace()

instead of  calling

> numpy.linspace()

Comment: Yes it's fine if you imported it that way, i.e. `from numpy import linspace`.

Comment: whatever you do just don't do `from numpy import *`

Comment: When you ask questions on SO, we strongly prefer that you use the module name, or the common alias, `np.linspace`.  It makes it clearer to us, and you, when you are using `numpy` (or `pandas`) and when you are using builtin function like python's `sum`.

Answer (score 2):

You can import it like this

`from numpy import linspace`

and then use it like this

```
a = linspace(1, 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, its completely fine when you are importing the function separately from the numpy such as

```
from numpy import linespace
#you can call the function by just writing its name
result=linespace(3,50)
```

but the convention is to use the name alias the pakage as np

```
 import numpy as np
 #then calling the function with short name
 result = np.linespace(3,50)
```

alias can be helpful when working with large number of libraries.and it also improves the code readability.

Answer (score 1):

If you import the function from the library directly there is nothing wrong with calling said function directly.

i.e.

```py
from numpy import linspace

# Then call linspace by itself
a = linspace(1, 10)
```

That being said, many find that having numpy (often shortened to np) in front of function names help improve code readability. As almost everyone does this with certain libraries (Tensorflow as tf, Numpy as np, Pandas as pd) some may view it in a poor light if you simply directly import and use the function.

I would recommend importing the library as the shortened name and then using it appropriately.

i.e.

```py
import numpy as np

# Then call np.linspace
a = np.linspace(1, 10)
```